# Proxy Request if ServerName does not match

Tags: apache, virtualhost, http-proxy

I have Ubuntu 20.04 machine and in that I have installed Apache server for handling the web requests. I want to run multiple websites on my single machine.

What I want is when request is coming from specific url then apache should load the specified directory for that url. If request is not coming from that specific url then request should be proxied.

To achieve this, I tried two methods but none worked

**Method One**

I created two virtual host files, one for request for proxy and another for pointing to a `DocumentRoot` when url matches

*vs1.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

*vs2.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName abc.example.com
   ServerAlias abc.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/my-website

</VirtualHost>
```

When I use above method, all the request points to `/var/www/my-website` as `DocumentRoot` but this should only be the case when url is `abc.example.com`. It is like the `vs1.conf` not even called and only `vs2.conf` file controlling the request.

**Method Two**

In this method, I decided to use just one virtual host file which looks like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName abc.example.com
   ServerAlias abc.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/my-website

   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case, when request is coming from `abc.example.com` then I see a blank page as if this request is not being handled. But when request is coming from url other than `abc.example.com` then they are proxied correctly.

So now I am clueless about how my configuration file should look like?

Comment: I'd say that your first virtual host is simply invalid, which is why the apache server ignores that host. You should get an error message about that in your server's error log files. That leaves the second virtual host. Since the apache http server always considered the first defined vhost the _default_ host (so here the second host, since the first is skipped), all requests are responded to by that one. Try adding a server name and a `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to the first one (does not really matter what you fill in), restart the http server and check if the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha. I added both virtual host in the same `.conf` file with the same sequence in the method one. This is working fine because first host is considered as default if request url does not match with the second host.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to understand what you tried to say in that comment.